# Installation of gulp doesn't succeed

Tags: npm, gulp

I tried reinstalling gulp, but keep getting the error below. Could you please help fix it? This is the [document](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start/) I'm referring for the same.

```
$ npm install gulp -g
(node:6408) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

added 47 packages, removed 22 packages, changed 301 packages, and audited 349 packages in 35s

7 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (3 low, 5 moderate)
```

Below is the message I see on running command `gulp sass`

```
D:\Projects\PWP-WP\wp-content\themes\blankslate-child>gulp sass
Error: Missing binding D:\Projects\PWP-WP\wp-content\themes\blankslate-child\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 11.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (D:\Projects\PWP-WP\wp-content\themes\blankslate-child\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\PWP-WP\wp-content\themes\blankslate-child\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\PWP-WP\wp-content\themes\blankslate-child\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:187:21)
```

Comment: No errors there, just warnings. Looks like it succeeded

Comment: But running command `gulp -v` outputs 
`CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: Unknown`. Why is local version unknown?

Comment: Also, how can I check if scss file can be compiled into css with gulp?

Comment: You've installed Gulp globally which is the CLI version. It appears that Gulp is not installed the project level (Local version: Unknown)

Comment: Is it okay to have installed it globally? This is the command `npm install gulp -g` I used to install

Comment: It depends! Some other packages require Gulp to be installed locally (in the project)

Comment: Thanks, can you advise as to how to install it locally?

Comment: remove the `-g` option so `npm install gulp` will install gulp in to the project's node modules.